# Calendar calculation API

Tags: library, osx, api, calendar

I am looking for a well supported (i.e. in active development or so mature that it can be a natural and uncontraversial choice) calendar library. I primarily need it to tell me when the next one or more dates are that match criteria I specify. The representative criteria I need to supply are:

Every 1-12 month(s) on the

1. last Saturday
2. last day
3. first Saturday
4. on # day

(Of course, if the library can handle these, it can likely handle a lot more that I may find useful at a later date.)

I will be using this library on OS X, so the preferred language of the library will be (in order of desirability) (a) Swift, (b) Objective-C, (c) C & (d) C++.

Apple's Cocoa classes supply two potential solutions:

1. The EventKit classes. The provided API can handle everything I mentioned above. The problem with it is that it requires that I interact directly with the user's calendar and this is something I want to avoid.
2. The NSCalendar & NSDateComponents classes. These can handle most of what I mentioned above, but I do not see a way to specify 'last', for example.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion for you would be the [wxWidgets](http://wxwidgets.org/) library's [wxDateTime](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_date_time.html) class.

wxWidgets is written in C++ is both mature, *(since 1992)*, and actively developed, is well documented and is cross platform.  It is free, *both Gratis & Open Source,* but is usable on commercial projects.

Taking your examples in order:

1. Every month on the last Saturday *[wxDateTime::SetToLastWeekDay](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_date_time.html#a55182141a6235de19c0bae356994e6f0)*
2. Every month on the last day *[wxDateTime::SetToLastMonthDay](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_date_time.html#a6d6bc203c75e55188c03d60d88600494)*
3. Every month on the first day *just set to first of the month*
4. Every month on day #  *just set to day # in the month*
5. Every month on the first Saturday *[wxDateTime::SetToWeekDay](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_date_time.html#a4687372ebe55a6aded83de6a639cde95)*
6. Every # months on the first Saturday *wxDateTime::SetToWeekDay in a loop*
7. Every # months on day #  *just set to day # in the month in a loop*
8. Every # months on the last Saturday *[wxDateTime::SetToLastWeekDay](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_date_time.html#a55182141a6235de19c0bae356994e6f0) in a loop*

You do not have to use the whole of the wxWidgets library, (which gives you a full GUI development library), you can just use parts of it by not building it as a monolithic library.

Additional calendar type members in wxDateTime:

- Date/Time parsing and formatting
- Date/Time comparisons & calculations
- Time zone calculations
- Gregorian/Julian calendar calculations
- Also includes the majority of holidays for IsWorkDay in selected countries.
- **Not** epoch bounded - you can perform calculations on dates prior to 1970 *the range of supported dates goes from about 4714 B.C. to some 480 million years in the future.*